# AngularJS directive link function not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/kz26/kH9wg/

I'm playing around with directives in AngularJS and have trying both the shorthand directive style (returning only the link function) and the longhand style (returning all or part of a directive definition object.

Unfortunately, I've only been able to get the directive working (which activates a jQuery popup) using the shorthand way defined in `popup2`. The longhand `popup2` directive doesn't seem to work at all, and in particular the `link` function in my definition object is never called. What do I need to do to make this explicit link declaration to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of your directives work with a small tweak to reuse the same module when creating the directives instead of overwriting the first one. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kH9wg/3/).

Instead of doing:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive('popover1'...

angular.module("app", []).directive('popover2'...
```

Do something like this:

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);

module.directive('popover1'...

module.directive('popover2'...
```

**Edit:** after looking at the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) I see you can do something similar to the original post as well like this:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('popover1'...

angular.module('app').directive('popover2'...
```

Omit the second parameter `[]` in subsequent calls after the first to `angular.module` to configure an existing module.

Comment: I had the same problem, reusing the module by omitting the second parameters is indeed the solution.

Answer (score 2):

And why the link function isnt called here?:

```
<div ng:app="app">
<div>
    <p test="">Hello!</p>
</div>
```

```
var module = angular.module("app", []);

module.directive('test', function() {
return {
        restrict: '',
        link: function () {
            console.log('linkfn');
        },
        compile: function() {
            console.log('compile');
        }
    };

});
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZWLzb/

Comment: The code in your fiddle looks the same as the one you posted in your response.